# WCF WebApi's Self-Hosting not accepting PUT verbs

Tags: wcf, wcf-web-api

I have put together a HTTP driven API using the [WCF WebAPI](http://wcf.codeplex.com) that uses the PUT verb.  When hosted inside of an MVC3 project that is hosted upon IIS Express, everything works as designed.

However, when I unit-test I'm occasionally wanting to test the transport aspects rather than just against my own resources.  My unit-tests fail with a 405 - MethodNotAllowed.  Again, exactly the same service hosted in IIS works (where I enabled the PUT and DELETE verbs in the configuration file).

**How can I get the 'self-hosted' service, as used in my testing, to accept these verbs too?**

The almost identical 'get' tests work, so I'm not expecting the concept of the following to be at fault.. hopefully...

```
[Test]
public void PutNewMachine()
{
    // Create new record to add
    var machine = new Machine
                      {
                          ID = 1,
                          Name = "One",
                          Description = "Machine #1",
                          Location = 1
                      };

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(
                                         HttpMethod.Put, 
                                         HOST + "/1"))
        {
            request.Content = new ObjectContent<Machine>(machine);

            using (var response = client.Send(request))
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(
                    HttpStatusCode.Created,
                    response.StatusCode,
                    "New record put should have been acknowledged "
                                    + "with a status code of 'Created'");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the setup to the test, I'm preparing the end-points using the following Autofac code (and again this works for the 'Get'):

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder
    .Register(c => new FakeDatabase())
    .As<IDatabase>()
    .SingleInstance();
builder
    .Register(c => new GenericRepository<Machine>(c.Resolve<IDatabase>()))
    .As<IResourceRepository<Machine>>();
builder
    .Register(c => new MachineService(c.Resolve<IResourceRepository<Machine>>()))
    .As<MachineService>();
Container = builder.Build();
Scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope();

host = new HttpServiceHost(typeof(MachineService), HOST);
host.AddDependencyInjectionBehavior<MachineService>(Container);
host.Open();
```

My service is defined in the following interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IResourceService<in TKey, TResource>
{
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "{key}")]
    TResource Get(TKey key);

    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "{key}")]
    TResource Put(TKey key, TResource resource);

    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
    TResource Post(TResource resource);

    [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", UriTemplate = "{key}")]
    void Delete(TKey key);
}
```

So, for example, if I have a MachineService, it implements the interface (both `class MachineService : IResourceService<string, Machine>` and `... : IResourceService<int, Machine>` have been trialled - Get = OK, Put = Nothing.

**EDIT**: I seem to be bouncing between InternalServerError and MethodNotAllowed errors - only when using the self-hosting.  I have ensured that I, as a user, have rights to open the port (Win7 + non-admin) but the results of that plus my choice of ports seems predicable functional for Get.   "Post" seems to be having similar issues! :-(

**EDIT2**: Interface has now changed to which works!

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IResourceService<in TKey, TResource>
{
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "{key}")]
    TResource Get(TKey key);

    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "{key}")]
    TResource Put(HttpRequestMessage<TResource> resourceRequest, TKey key);

    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "{key}")]
    TResource Post(HttpRequestMessage<TResource> resourceRequest, TKey key);

    [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", UriTemplate = "{key}")]
    void Delete(TKey key);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it with a non-generic service interface?

Comment: Try using HttpConfigurableServiceHost instead of HttpServiceHost.

Comment: Yes, I had started with non-generic and still have a test service that exhibits the same problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing PUT or POST works for me when I change the method signature to accept a HttpRequestMessage request instead of T itself.

Comment: I have no idea why I would have thought that may work, instead I'm now accepting the HttpRequestMessage<T>.  The only issue I now have is it seems my 'request' I'm issuing in the tests are not correctly formed - but at least I'm getting closer!

Comment: @Ray: Maybe because, IMHO at least, it should have worked :-) It does work in a web application. I have reported the issue [here](http://bit.ly/m7ekUP)