# How to POST a POCO with WCF WebApi's HttpClient

Tags: wcf, wcf-client, wcf-web-api

I'm using the WCF WebApi stack (Preview 4) via NuGet (pkg version 0.3.0) and cannot seem to figure out how to "POST a POCO" using `HttpClient`.

Given the following:

```vb
Public Class MyInfo
    Public Property MyDate As DateTime
    Public Property MyId As Guid
End Class

...
Dim value = New MyInfo With {.MyDate = Today, .MyId = Guid.NewGuid()}

Using client as New HttpClient(baseUri)
    Using response = client.Post(requestUri, New ObjectContent(Of MyInfo)(value))
        ' Do stuff
    End Using
End Using
...
```

When the `Post` method is called, I get the following exception:

```vb
The 'XmlSerializer' serializer cannot serialize the type 'MyInfo'.

at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Http.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.GetSerializerForType(Type type)
at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Http.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.OnWriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream stream, HttpContentHeaders contentHeaders, TransportContext context)
at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Http.MediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object instance, Stream stream, HttpContentHeaders contentHeaders, TransportContext context)
at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Http.ObjectContent.WriteToStreamInternal(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Http.ObjectContent.SerializeToStream(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LoadIntoBuffer(Int32 maxBufferSize)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientChannel.PrepareWebRequestForContentUpload(HttpWebRequest webRequest, HttpRequestMessage request)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientChannel.CreateAndPrepareWebRequest(HttpRequestMessage request)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientChannel.Send(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Send(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Send(HttpRequestMessage request)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Post(Uri requestUri, HttpContent content)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Post(String requestUri, HttpContent content)
...
```

This is using the NuGet 0.3.0 package.

I've tried adding `<Serializable()>` and even `<DataContract()>` to `MyInfo`, but that didn't help. Am I just doing something wrong?

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398134/wcf-webapis-self-hosting-not-accepting-put-verbs) here on StackOverflow where it looks like someone is doing something similar to what I did above. I've even duplicated his work (guessing that his `Machine` object was a simple POCO like my `MyInfo` is) and ran into the same "cannot serialize" exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up finding the problem myself.  I was missing the media type.  I changed the `Post` method to look like:

```
Using client as New HttpClient(baseUri)
    Using response = client.Post(requestUri, New ObjectContent(Of MyInfo)(value, "text/xml"))
        ' Do stuff
    End Using
End Using
```

and it started working.  I guess that makes sense.  For some reason, I thought that there was some sort of default media type precedence built-in so that you didn't have to go out of your way to specify the media type each time.  Maybe there is, but I'm still doing something wrong?

**Update:**

My original problem actually had nothing to do with the media type, even though that actually did fix/workaround the problem.  The problem seems to happen when `MyInfo` is nested inside of a `Module` like this.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim value = New MyInfo With {.MyDate = Today, .MyId = Guid.NewGuid()}
        Dim payload As HttpContent = New ObjectContent(Of MyInfo)(value)

        Using client as New HttpClient(baseUri)
            Using response = client.Post(requestUri, New ObjectContent(Of MyInfo)(value))
                ' Do stuff
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

    Public Class MyInfo
        Public Property MyDate As DateTime
        Public Property MyId As Guid
    End Class

End Module
```

Once `MyInfo` moved outside of the `Module`, the error no longer happens.  It's also worth noting that while the media type is no longer required to prevent the exception, the lack of it results in no `Content-Type` header, which may not fly server-side as the server may not know how to deserialize the message body.  In my case, I needed to leave the media type in so that the request would include a `Content-Type: application/xml` header for the server's sake.

Comment: Instead of hard coding in "text/xml" I ended up using XmlMediaTypeFormatter.DefaultMediaType.MediaType (which is "application/xml" -- a "better" media type anyhow).  Still would like to know if I could avoid doing this and just fall back on some sane defaults.